# Can you still get and use Auriel's bow when you join the Dawn Guard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements, skyrim-dawnguard

Just got the Dawn Guard DLC and noticed the achievement to use Auriel's bow, but I was I want to be with the Dawn Guard.

Do you still get Auriel's bow if your sided with the Dawn Guard or do you have to be a vampire?

The bow is supposed to help the vampires and also leads to an achievement using it (and I'm all about the achievements) and I don't want to start a new character and complete the main quest and Dawn Guard because it takes too long

Answer (score 4):

The bow itself doesn't change, so yes, you can use it.  It's still a powerful sun-damage weapon. What changes is whether or not you use your companion's blood to make the arrows that blot out the sun.

Bethesda games often have their story splits early for achievement purposes, but if you're achievement farming, the best choice is to make a hard save right before a point of no return on the decision. Then you can play through each branch, make a hard save at the end of that branch, reload the first save, and once you've obtained all of the achievements, load and keep the branch with the outcome you wanted.

Comment: If you're not achievement farming then go through as the Dawnguard as per your playthrough and, whenever you want, start a new playthough with a character that will follow the Volkihar Vampire clan as opposed to the Dawnguard. This way you still get the achievements whilst enjoying all the gameplay available. Plus, being a Vampire Lord is quite fun and you get a lot of power out of it, and you get a nice big castle! FYI you can be a Vampire Lord and side with the Dawnguard, but what fun is that?!

Comment: -1 for not addressing the question, which is about the achievement related to Auriel's Bow.

Answer (score -2):

If you sided with the Dawn Guard, you get neither the bow now the Shield.
HOWEVER, if you are on PC, just console command it.
If you don't know the ID number, jus' type, "help Auriel," and everything associated with that name will come up

Comment: Wrong.  The differences between the two quest lines are trivial.  You get both bow & shield either way.